# Using a ViewController variable in segue.destination

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

In the code below, I'm trying to use the variable `controller` to fill in the type of my destination segue at the bottom. But instead I get an error message that says `controller` is undeclared. It's declared right there on the second line! I can see it! I realize there are many alternatives to using segue identifiers but I'm more interested in learning why this doesn't work.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var controller: UIViewController

    switch segue.identifier {
    case "ASegue":
        controller = AViewController()
    case "BSegue":
        controller = BViewController()
    case "CSegue":
        controller = CViewController()
    default:
        controller = AViewController()
    }

    if let vc = segue.destination as? controller { //Use of undeclared type 'controller'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `controller` is not a type. It's an instance (foolishly created for no reason). The entire structure of this switch is wrong. You presumably know the controller type based on the segue, so just cast!

Comment: `controller` contains an instance of a view controller, not its type. That's a good example why types are supposed to be named uppercased and instances lowercased. What are you going to accomplish? If the controllers are designed in Interface Builder the default initializer `AViewController()` doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I have six possible segues and the code for each is identical with the exception of the type of view controller. So much repetition in my case statement seemed like a bad idea so I tried to condense things a bit. Had I known I was being foolish I probably wouldn't have ended up here in the first place. I now understand that Swift is a statically typed language and that the complier needs to know types before the program can be run.

Comment: If there is a common property in every destination view controller create a protocol with this property as requirement and adopt the protocol. Then you need only **once** `if let vc = segue.destination as? MyControllerProtocol`

Comment: I had to change `if let vc` to `if var vc` but otherwise it worked! Brilliant, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A cast must be to a *type* (literal), not a *variable*.

And in any case you cannot conflate all your action into a single `controller` variable as you seem to want to do, exactly because they *are* different types.

So you would simply move the cast into each case of the switch, casting to the type that you expect for that segue's destination controller, and doing the appropriate work on *that* `controller` in *that* case:

```
switch segue.identifier {
case "ASegue":
    if let controller = segue.destination as? AViewController {
        // do stuff
    }
case "BSegue":
    if let controller = segue.destination as? BViewController {
// etc.
```

Perhaps a slightly cleaner way of expressing this is to forget the identifier and just go for the view controller class, *if* each possible segue has a different view controller class:

```
switch segue.destination {
case let controller as AViewController:
    // populate controller
case let controller as BViewController:
    // populate controller
// etc.
```